# Check to see if the target of a click contains several substrings

Tags: javascript, onclick, target

This seems relatively straightforward, but it's giving me trouble. I want to do something on all clicks that fit certain criteria so I start by putting this in the header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.onclick = function(e) { 
    alert(e.target);
};</script>
```

This alerts  "www.chorizon.com/link?page=155". Now, this works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.onclick = function(e) { 
    var test="www.chorizon.com/link?page=155";
    if((test.indexOf("link") > -1) && (test.indexOf("page=155") > -1)){
        alert('yes')
    }
};</script>
```

So why doesn't this work?

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.onclick = function(e) { 
    if((e.target.indexOf("link") > -1) && (e.target.indexOf("page=155") > -1)){
        alert('yes')
    }
};</script>
```

Is there something I need to do to e.target to use it like a regular string?

Comment: `alert(typeof (e.target));` will help you understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're confused is because **alert() is not a debugging tool**, you're really getting an object containing a reference to a DOM element, not a string, it's just converted to a string as `alert` can't display objects, and that object has no `indexOf` method!

Start using the console for debugging.

Not sure what you're trying to get, but it looks like an URL, so I'm guessing it's the href property of an anchor, but that would redirect the page, hence the uncertainty ?

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    var url = e.target.href || '';

    if( url.indexOf("link") > -1 && url.indexOf("page=155") > -1) {
        alert('yes')
    }

}, false);
```

Comment: Wait, how do I get the attributes of e.target to the console?